# Вывод текста из файла в консоль

Tags: c

Не могу найти ошибку при выводе текста из файла в консоль, при попытке использования функции ничего не происходит.

```
void instruction()
{
FILE *instruction1;
    char ch;
    instruction1 = fopen("Instruction.txt", "r");
    if ((instruction1 = fopen("Instruction.txt", "r")) == NULL)

    {

        printf("Oshibka pri otkrytii faila!\n");

    }
        ch = getc(instruction1);
     while (ch != EOF);
     {
         putchar(ch);
         ch = getc(instruction1);
     }
     fclose(instruction1);
     system("pause");


}
```

Comment: 1.Вы серьезно считаете, что до него с первого раза не дошло, поэтому открываете его во второй раз: `if ((instruction1 = fopen("Instruction.txt", "r")) == NULL)`??? (по-честному, уж лучше первое "открытие" убрать, раз здесь хоть как-то проверяете результат. либо в этой строчке просто уберите `=fopen()`, чтобы вышло `if (instruction1==NULL)` )  2.В случае ошибки, таки надо что-то сделать. Хоть из программы выйти. А то Вы просто сообщили о ней и дальше "читаете" файл, будто он открыт.  3.`getc()` возвращает значение типа `int`, а не `char`. 4. Допустим, Вы прочитали символ из файла. А дальше что?

Comment: Ну, он выведет мне его на экран, а потом прочитаем следующий символ...Или не так? И так он будет делать до конца файла.

Comment: Да, чего-то я погорячился..`putchar()` должен вывести на экран.

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, но все-равно не работает.

Comment: А еще, у Вас странный цикл какой-то `while (ch != EOF);` - ему точка с запятой там совсем не нужна ;-)

Comment: Ооох, вот я неаккуратный, спасибо, все заработало)